# AWS : Create Cloud Watch log group subscriber to Elastic Search on another AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-elasticsearch

I have two AWS accounts,  one AWS account "A" contains Cloud Watch with data streaming in it (previously I created subscriber to send logs to Elastic Search instance in the same account using the AWS console and it work just fine)
So i remove the previous subscriber and created one for account B (using account B ARN & Domain)
when i tried to stream the logs i ran into the following error in the Lambda that forwarding the logs:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "{\"statusCode\":403,\"responseBody\":{\"Message\":\"User: arn:aws:sts::<account A id>:assumed-role/lambda_elasticsearch_execution/LogsToElasticsearchEx_cloud-watch-elasticsearch is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost\"}}",
    "stack": [
        "Error: {\"statusCode\":403,\"responseBody\":{\"Message\":\"User: arn:aws:sts::<account A id>:assumed-role/lambda_elasticsearch_execution/LogsToElasticsearchEx_cloud-watch-elasticsearch is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost\"}}",
        "    at _homogeneousError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:13:12)",
        "    at postError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:30:51)",
        "    at done (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:57:7)",
        "    at fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:69:7)",
        "    at Object.fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:105:16)",
        "    at /var/task/index.js:42:25",
        "    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:176:13)",
        "    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)",
        "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)",
        "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
    ]
}
```

I have the following IAM roles:

**account A lambda role**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "es:ESHttpPost",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:es:*:<account B id>:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Account B role (with trust relationship):**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "es:ESHttpPost",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Trust relationship:

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account A id>:role/lambda_elasticsearch_execution"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I followed the guides bellow but still running in the same error

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

does anyone have an idea for what i'm missing ?

Thanks in advances!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... To solve this it not so hard then you think.
Let's start Account A (number 1234567890) have in cloudwatch the log groups. Account B  (number 0987654321)contains the elasticsearch  (ES)running. Account A the lambda is running under/with the role name (SentCloudwatchToES).
This is the starting point. Now go to account B, open they policy of the ES. This is the policy you have created during the creation of the ES stack. You can find it by ES part in AWS! (goto ES in AWS, click on domain, click on action, modify acces policy) Edit the policy, with following section:

```
   {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/service-role/SentCloudwatchToES",
        ]
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:<YOUR-REGION>:0987654321:domain/<YOUR-ES-DOMIAN>/*"
    }
```

Safe it, and wait a couple of min, so that AWS can process the policy in ES.
Now setup/configure the log stream to ES from account A to account B.